# Vue-EventBus works only when it has the dedicated fuction for itself?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-visualization

I came across a bug while transferring data using eventbus.
What I tried to do is
passing the data from 'Quoteinput.vue' to 'Quotebar.vue' to update the progress bar length
depending on the length of data which is in 'Quoteinput.vue'.

It was successfully done when I set two functions in 'Quoteinput.vue'.

**One is for Pushing data to the array.** 
**The other one is only for the eventbus.**

See the code below.

=**Quoteinput.vue**=

```
<template>
  <div>
      <!-- <div class='input-group' style='position:relative'> -->
          <div class='input-group-prepend'>
              <span class = 'input-group-text'> Type your Quote</span>
          </div>


          <textarea class ='form-control' aria-label='with textarea' v-model="message"></textarea><hr><hr>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" @click='addingmessage'>submit my quote</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" @click='addprogress'>progresscheck</button>

          <textbox class='messagebox' v-for='value in quote' :typedquote ='value'></textbox>

          <!-- v model 이랑 v-for를 통해서 추가하면 되겠구만 -->
          <!-- Text box showing -->

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import textbox from './quotebox.vue'
import {ProgressBus} from '../../main.js'

export default {

    data(){
        return {
            quote:[],
            message:'',
        }
    },
    components:{
        textbox
    },
    methods:{
        addingmessage(){
            this.quote.push(this.message)

            // 프로그레스 버스가 여기서 쿠오트 데이터를 물어가지고, 쿠오트바로 가져가야한다.
        },
        addprogress(){
            ProgressBus.$emit('quotedata',this.quote)

        }
    }

}
```

However, this wasn't my original plan. I tried to put prgressbus and pushing the array within one function which is addingmessage(). like below.

```
methods:{
    addingmessage(){
        this.quote.push(this.message)
        ProgressBus.$emit('quotedata',this.quote)


    }
```

Why did this error happen? and what should I do to fix this?

The code that actually draws the progress bar is as below.

**=Quotebar.vue=**

```
<template>


<div class="progress" style="height: 20px;">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" :style="{width:10*completion+'%'}" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>

</template>

<script>
import {ProgressBus} from '../../main.js'

export default {

    created(){
        ProgressBus.$on('quotedata',(value)=>{
            this.completion= value.length 
        })
    },

    data(){
        return{
            completion: 0
        }
    }



}
</script>

<style scoped>


</style>
```

For your understanding, I here attach simple diagram for the structure.
[image]

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious what is the error message. I think you could async/await function for work sequentially.

```
methods:{
    async addingmessage() {
        await this.quote.push(this.message);
        await ProgressBus.$emit('quotedata',this.quote);
    }
}
```